# cluster google map markers and zoom in on cluster

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

When a user is zoomed out on the gmsmapview the markers get very close together( there is only a max of like 100 markers). Is there a way to zoom in on markers that are extremely close when a user clicks on them? Rather than just clicking on each individual marker?

Comment: Why not using markers clusters..this tecnique show a markers cluster with the numer of cluster in the area and clicking the zoom to marker

Comment: Thats what I ended up doing. Post as an answer and i'll accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not using markers clusters..this tecnique show a markers cluster with the numer of cluster in the area and clicking the zoom to marker

I think you need somethings like this: Show also the [sample](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclusterer/examples/simple_example.html?compiled)  and here the complete [source](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclusterer/src/markerclusterer.js)

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
      function initialize() {
        var center = new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419);

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 3,
          center: center,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        });

        var markers = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
          var dataPhoto = data.photos[i];
          var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(dataPhoto.latitude,
              dataPhoto.longitude);
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latLng
          });
          markers.push(marker);
        }
        var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers);
      }
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
```